# Need to exclude field values from Sitecore search index viewer is not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I need to eliminate/exclude a field id/value in config. This is what I have in my config but still it's not eliminating my field id. I need help to eliminate/exclude the field values in Sitecore.

```
<include hint="list:ExcludeField">             
<fieldId>{A0CB3965-8884-4C7A-8815-B6B2E5CED162}</fieldId> </include>
```

I need help excluding the field value and finding a field id for the ones in image.

In detail, how do I exclude all the highlighted ones from index search?

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615382/how-to-exclude-fields-form-being-indexed-with-sitecore-search-new-method

Comment: Yes I have seen that forum but I not able to find out the feild Guid id so that i can include that value in siteconfig as i have more than 100 feilds that needs to excluded from the sitesearch                                                              <include hint="list:IncludeField">
    <!-- some field you'd want to include -->
    <fieldId>{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}</fieldId>
  </include>
  <include hint="list:ExcludeField">
    <!-- __revision field -->
    <fieldId>{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}</fieldId>
     </include>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find Field Guid go to template manager and select the template which has your field. Then expand the tree to find FieldItem and grab Field Guid from FieldItem's quick info section.